# Sending contact for to different server/domain before sending

Tags: forms, html-email, email-client, php

I have two websites and I would need to make a contact form on other of the sites. But the PHP that actually sends the mail is on other server.

So the form is on www.domain1.com/contactform.html / server1
And hitting the send button there it would send the info to www.domain2.com/mail.php / server2

I think this should be possible but is there any security issues on this?

Also I would need to send the end users email (to who someone is contacting to) also to the server2... maybe on a hidded field? But can spamspot recognize that address from hidden field? Or people can change the address to different?

Hopefully you understand what I intend to do. The questions are more that is it secure to do it like that and are there better ways to do it.

Answer (score 0):

From my personal experience, it would make more sense to just make another mail.php file on the domain1.com contact form.
As far as sending the end users email, you could put it in a hidden field, and that'd work fine.

Comment: Yes, but server1 doesnt have php support, thats why i need to do it this way.

Comment: What exactly is server1 running?

Comment: Like what server software? How could your server not possibly have some sort of server-side language that is compatible with it?

Answer (score 0):

It would have the same security issues, if you had contactform.html and mail.php on the same server.